# Помогите оптимизировать программу для задачи на Python "Красивый шарф"

Tags: python, алгоритм

Всем привет решаю задачу на пайтон. Все вроде бы должно работать хорошо, но сайт выдает 0 баллов за **Превышеное максимальное время работы**. Теперь при вводе данных выдает `48`, а не `11`.Кто поможет мне, заранее спасибо!
Красивый шарф
Алиса решила поздравить своего друга с началом нового учебного года. Впереди холодная осень, поэтому она решила связать для него собственными руками шарф.

Незаметно для друга Алиса узнала, что ему большего всего нравятся k различных цветов. Алиса приняла решение связать шарф размером n × m, в котором будут чередоваться полоски различных цветов. Её друг никогда не ищет легких путей, поэтому она решила, что шарф с горизонтальными или вертикальными полосками покажется ему слишком «примитивным». Алиса решила, что полоски определённо должны быть диагональными!

Закончив вязать шарф, Алиса вспомнила, что один из k цветов её друг считает особенным! Это цвет c, который по его мнению приносит школьникам удачу на олимпиадах по информатике. И Алисе стало невероятно интересно, сколько фрагментов шарфа имеют именно такой цвет. Шарф получился очень большим, Алиса очень устала, пока его вязала, поэтому сама она уже не может ответить на этот вопрос и просит вас о помощи...

Более формально шарф можно представить в виде таблицы размером n × m, каждая клетка которой покрашена в один из k цветов. Цвета нумеруются от 1 до k.

**Первая строка таблицы покрашена в цвета 1, 2, ..., k, 1, 2, ..., k и т.д. Каждая следующая строка получена из предыдущей сдвигом влево на одну клетку. Таким образом, таблица состоит из диагональных полос.**

При `n = 4`, `m = 8` и `k = 3` таблица будет иметь следующий вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
По данным числам n, m, k и c определите, сколько всего клеток покрашено в цвет c.

Входные данные
Первая строка входных данных содержит натуральное число n — ширину шарфа.

Вторая строка входных данных содержит натуральное число m — длину шарфа.

Третья строка входных данных содержит натуральное число k — количество любимых цветов друга Алисы.

Числа `n`, `m` и `k` не превосходят `109`.

Четвёртая строка входных данных содержит натуральное число c — номер особенного цвета `(1 ≤ c ≤ k)`.

Выходные данные
Программа должна вывести одно целое число — количество клеток шарфа, которые покрашены в цвет c.

Примечание:
**Обратите внимание, что ответ в этой задаче может превышать возможное значение 32-битной целочисленной переменной, поэтому необходимо использовать 64-битные целочисленные типы данных (тип int64 в языке Pascal, тип long long в C++, тип long в Java и C#).**

Система оценки

Решения, правильно работающие, когда число n не превосходит 10, будут оцениваться в 16 баллов.

Решения, правильно работающие, когда одно из чисел n или m делится нацело на k, будут оцениваться в 16 баллов.

Решения, правильно работающие, когда числа n и m не превосходят 800, будут оцениваться в 40 баллов.

Решения, правильно работающие, когда числа n и m не превосходят 105, будут оцениваться в 60 баллов.

Замечание

Картинка соответствует примеру из условия. Шарф имеет размеры 4 × 8 и состоит из клеток трёх цветов. В цвет 1 покрашены 11 клеток.

Входные данные:

```
4
8
3
1
```

Выходные данные:

```
11
```

А вот мой код:

```py
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
k = int(input())
c = int(input())

color_counts = [0] * k

# Левая часть диагоналей
left_diagonals = n - k
left_diagonal_length = k - 1
color_counts[c-1] += left_diagonals * left_diagonal_length

# Средняя часть диагоналей
middle_diagonals = n // k
middle_diagonal_length = k
color_counts[c-1] += middle_diagonals * middle_diagonal_length

# Правая часть диагоналей
right_diagonals = n - k
right_diagonal_length = n % k
color_counts[c-1] += right_diagonals * right_diagonal_length

result = color_counts[c-1] * m

print(result)
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Ваш код работает?

Comment: Получается да работает @MBo

Comment: Но может вы сможете дать мне совет

Comment: Ваш код тормозит потому что вы выделяете огромный массив. Хотя из него используется только один элемент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведённый код квадратичный, он, вероятно, даёт правильные ответы, но по времени никак не пройдёт.

Давайте посмотрим на матрицу, например, на число 2.

Число `c` лежит на диагоналях.
Левая часть диагоналей -  неполные, обрезаются левым краем, их длина меньше `n`
Потом идёт средняя часть диагоналей - они идут от верха до низа, их длина `n`
Потом правая часть - диагонали стартуют на правом краю и идут донизу, они тоже неполные

Остаётся найти количество диагоналей во всех частях и диапазоны их длин для левой и правой части (длины составляют арифметическую прогрессию, так что сумму найти несложно, главное - выяснить параметры этих прогрессий)

Время работы константное O(1)

```
def countc(n, m, k, c):
    n, m = min(n, m), max(n, m)  #ввиду симметрии задачи обеспечим m>=n
    cnt = 0

    #номер последней c-содержащей левой диагонали
    numld = max(0, 1 + (n - 1 - c) // k)  
    cnt += (2*c + (numld-1)*k) * numld // 2

    #номер последней c-содержащей средней (полной длины) диагонали 
    md = (m - 1 - c) // k
    cnt += n*(md-numld+1)

    r1 = md + 1
    #номер последней c-содержащей правой диагонали
    r2 = (n + m - 1 - c) // k
    rd = max(0, r2 - r1 + 1)
    len1 = n - (c + r1*k - m)
    len2 = n - (c + r2*k - m)
    cnt += rd*(len1+len2)//2

    return cnt
```

Comment: cейчас вообще ничего не правильно получилось

Comment: но спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вы уже успели всё реализовать и проверить??

Comment: ну я работаю не один)

Comment: все смогли решить проблему, спасибо вам!